# using explode (empty delimiter)

Tags: php

**(Entry level question)** I'm having an issue using explode. I have an integer that's always 5 digits assigned to a $variable. I want to explode every individual number separately. I've read examples where there's a delimiter, such as ; , a space or something else, but what if there is no delimiter?

Example:

```
 $variable = '12345'; // explode into 5 separate numbers
 $exploded = explode('', $variable);
 var_dump($exploded);
```

Output error:

```
 explode(): Empty delimiter
 bool(false)
```

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): `If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.`. Use [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead

Comment: `$variable[0]` will be 1, `$variable[1]` will be 2, and so on... No explosion needed.

Answer (score 0):

"$variable[0] will be 1, $variable[1] will be 2, and so on... No explosion needed. –  frz3993 8 mins ago"